# Why doesn't my Intel Optane application recognize my Optane hardware?

Tags: windows-10, optane

I am trying to use an Optane chip, and I believe I have installed it correctly, but the application for it says

> **Cannot Enable Intel Optane Memory**
>
> Your system appears to be Intel Optane memory ready but no Intel Optane memory modules were detected in your computer.

Windows device manager shows an item in the category "Disk drives" called "INTEL MEMPEK1W032GA", which is the part number for an Optane chip, so it is at least correctly attached to the motherboard.

My motherboard is an ASRock X299 Taichi, and I have flashed it to the latest stable BIOS release. The [manufacturer's spec sheet](http://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/X299%20Taichi/index.asp#Specification) says that each M2 slot "Supports Intel® Optane™ Technology".

I have also confirmed that

- I am running Windows 10 on a SSD, and booting with UEFI.
- The boot disk has more than 5MB of unallocated space, which I believe is at the end of the disk, based on the output of `diskpart`.
- The SATA controllers are set to use Intel RST mode.

Comment: Did a little research and this may be the issue or else help others with the same problem so I added as an answer and referenced all correlated material I found that helped me come up with this potential solution—Look forward to hearing whether or not this helps you any with your issue and this motherboard and configuration.

Answer (score 3):

### Cannot Enable Intel Optane Memory - Potential Solution

Go to the **UEFI boot menu** by pressing <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> or <kbd>**`Del`**</kbd> at system startup, and then from the <kbd>**`Boot`**</kbd> tab options, you will want to **Disable** the <kbd>**`CSM`**</kbd> option—see the **4.4.1** labeled section below and ensure these options and sub-options from 1-4 are configured accordingly as well if disabling the CSM option alone doesn't resolve.

[image]

---

### Why

According to **Intel** regarding the [Intel Optane Memory](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/optane-memory.html)

- > ### [4.4.1   Manual SATA Controller Mode Switch](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/optane-memory/intel-optane-memory-user-installation.pdf) <sup>(Pg. 18)</sup>
  >
  > If your computer’s System BIOS does not support automatic SATA Controller switching, you will need to switch the SATA controller
  >   manually, pior to installing the OS. Consult your system or
  >   motherboard vendor’s User Manual for manual BIOS SATA controller mode
  >   switching procedures.
  >
  > 1. Prepare the installation media as outlined in *chapter 3* (recommended optional step)
  > 2. Power on your system and boot to the System BIOS (typically done by pressing F2 or Delete)
  >
  >    **Note:** Make sure your System BIOS is up to date with support for
  >      Intel® Optane™ memory. Consult your vendors support website for the
  >      latest Intel® Optane™ memory supported System BIOS.
  > 3. Change the System BIOS settings to the following:
  >
  >    i. SATA Mode = ‘Intel® RST Premium and System Acceleration with
  >      Intel®
  >         Optane™ Technology’ or ‘Intel® RST and System Acceleration with Intel®
  >         Optane™ Technology’
  >
  >    ii. UEFI = Enabled
  >
  >    iii. CSM = Disabled
  >
  >    iv. Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) enabled
  >
  >    v. M.2 Port Remapping enabled
  > 4. Install the Windows* 10 OS
  >
  >    **Note:** After the second restart, the Intel® Optane™ memory
  >      application may take several seconds to pop up. If the the Intel®
  >      Optane™ memory application does not pop up automatically it can be
  >      launched by searching for ‘Intel® Optane™ memory in Windows* File
  >      Search.
  >
  >    ***Consult your system or motherboard vendors User Manual and support
  >      site for details on how to update these settings.***
  >
  > <sub>[source](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/optane-memory/intel-optane-memory-user-installation.pdf)</sub>

---

According to the [ASRock X299 Taichi manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/X299%20Taichi.pdf) <sup>(Pg. 21 & 103)</sup>

- > 1. Enter **UEFI** by pressing  or  during system startup.
  > 2. Select “**Boot** > **CSM**” from the menu.
  > 3. Set "**Launch Storage OpROM policy**" to "**UEFI only**".
  > 4. Press **F10** to **Save** and **Exit**.
  >
  > <sub>(Pg. 21)</sub>
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **CSM**
  >
  > Enable to launch the Compatibility Support Module. Please do not
  >   disable unless you’re running a WHCK test. If you are using Windows
  >   8.1 64-bit and all of your devices support UEFI, you may also disable CSM for faster boot speed.
  >
  > <sub>(Pg. 103)</sub>
  >
  > <sub>[source](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/X299%20Taichi.pdf)</sub>

---

According to the [Cannot enable Optane Memory](https://communities.intel.com/thread/114608) Intel community thread

- > ***DavidC2 May 26, 2017 2:12 PM (in response to weevilone)***
  >
  > I may be able to help as well. I've had the same message during my
  >   Optane Memory install. The trick was to disable CSM, or Compatibility
  >   Support Module.
  >
  > On my motherboard which is Gigabyte H270-HD3 the way
  >   to show CSM menu was:
  >
  > BIOS tab --> Enable Windows 8/10 Features to
  >   Windows 10 WHQL --> Once that's done you see an option for CSM support
  >   --> Set to disable
  >
  > Their videos tell you to disable CSM in order for Optane Memory to
  >   work. Among others. Try this one though.
  >
  > <sub>[source](https://communities.intel.com/thread/114608)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Compatibility Support Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Compatibility_Support_Module)

Comment: I tried verifying that the BIOS settings were as suggested, and I noticed that in the SATA settings, it said that PCIe remapping was disabled for M2_1. When I get a chance, I'll try moving the chip to a different M2 slot and see if that allows me to enable that option.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Be sure to check out page 24 and 41 from the [ASRock X299 Taichi manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/X299%20Taichi.pdf) too. I searched the entire document by pressing `Ctrl`+`F` for "m.2" and read all sections and notes where `m.2` was listed. I thought pages 24 and 41 were interesting about "*`M2_#` being occupied by a SATA-type M.2 device, `SATA3_#` will be disabled*" so be sure to check that out too as you may find that detail helpful as well. I'll add to my answer later if you confirm that this is helpful as well in getting resolved. I'll dig more if needed

Answer (score 1):

The full procedure is :

1. Ensure the BIOS is updated to an Optane Ready version, and that you have CSM (or Legacy BIOS) disabled.
2. Install windows under UEFI in a GPT partition.
   The end of the boot volume must contain at least 
   5MB of continuous unallocated space.
3. Update windows completely
4. Download and install the latest Optane software from the website of the
   manufacturer of your motherboard.
   It might offer a one click install which changes the BIOS settings for you,
   so follow the instructions and let the system reboot as required.
   In the end you will reboot into Windows and if the Optane program will
   appear asking for Enable then installation is successful.
5. If after enabling Optane is still hidden in both your OS and BIOS,
   unplug all disks except the boot disk, then reboot to a Command window and enter:

   ```
   diskpart
   list disk (you should be able to see the memory module, note its number)
   select disk X (Optane disk)
   Clean all
   ```

   [image]
6. Alternatively, you may reset Optane module from within the BIOS.
   This may vary for motherboard brand and model:

   1. Open your UEFI BIOS Utility.
   2. Switch to "Advanced Mode" by pressing the F7 key.
   3. Go to the "Advanced" tab.
   4. Scroll down to "Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology" and enter.
   5. Select your Optane module. May display as something along the lines of "PCIe 1.0, Intel MEMPEK1W0......", enter.
   6. Under "Disk Actions:" there should be an option to "Reset to non-Optane." This option will reset your module and allow you to detect and enable it again.
   7. Restart the computer and follow again the entire procedure.

   [image: image2]

References:

- [Optane Memory cannot be detected after reinstalling OS (not disabled before)](https://communities.intel.com/message/481246).
- [Intel Optane Memory Installation and User Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/optane-memory/intel-optane-memory-user-installation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe download/run SetupRST.exe at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29647/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Driver-Installation-Software-with-Intel-Optane-Memory?fbclid=IwAR178oFSeu0cX-YZlcimqKEnRFOeT_XjR9oYbEXQqnat_txoZNLaXjvq5rc and use the Intel® Optane™ Memory and Storage Management application to locate it. Not sure. Good luck!